# Can I preview a report in BIDS on different servers by changing Environments like it works for SSIS projects?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, bids

I am working on a report in Visual Studio (BIDS). I want to preview it and by default, it previews against my local SQL server as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/previewing-reports?view=sql-server-2017
What I want to achieve is to also preview it in a UAT Server/ Test etc, without deploying it to said servers SSRS reports. 
I SSIS I can run a process against different servers by changing the environment from the Configuration manager drop-down list.

The report is not relevant as its the whole project I want to apply this functionality to.

Changing the configuration manager has no effect on the preview of the report.

I have my deployment environments set to work with different SSRS servers but it has no effect on the preview.

I was sure it used to be possible when I was still working in 2005. However, I am losing that confidence. The entire Solution (includes SSIS and SSAS) was worked on by multiple different ppl with different styles over time. Some part seem to have been corrupted, hacked over time. It took a while to realize what a mess SSIS project was in with regards to the data sources. 
I couldn't find anything on this on slack and did google it quite a lot. Maybe I am missing the correct vocabulary to hit the correct search term.

I am not just looking for a solution, I am looking for confirmation whether this is at all possible. A part of me still hopes it may be something broken in the project/Solution file.

Comment: Couldn't you add the different Environments as **Data Sources** and switch the Datasets between them? Or you could make the data source an expression that uses a parameter for the environment.

Answer (score 0):

As @HannoverFist wrote, you can make a dynamic data source. Here is an example:

```
="data source=" & Parameters!Server.Value & ";initial catalog=" & Parameters!Database.Value
```

[image]